# Two circles inscribed in isosceles triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

$$\triangle ABC :AC =BC$$
$$P \in AB$$

$k(O;r)$ is inscribed in $\triangle APC$; $k_2(O_2; r_2)$ is inscribed    in $\triangle BPC$;

$D, G$ are points of contact of the circles with $CP$.

---

Show that $DG=\frac {|AP - BP|}{2}$.

---

I think that it will be helpful if we find point $A_1$, such that $BA_1 = AP$. Now we have to prove $2DG=PA_1$.
[image]

Comment: Usually in solving problems you are required to use all the given conditions. In the discussion of the first deleted answer you were one step to finish: $DG=PG-PD=\frac {PB-\require{cancel} \cancel{BC}-AP+\cancel{AC}}{2}=\frac {PB-AP}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I got it later. Thank you!

Comment: Look for similar shapes to prove the DP:AP and GP:BP are of the same proportions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $|AC|=|BC|=a$, $|AB|=c$,
$|AP|=m$, $|CP|=d$.

\begin{align} 
|CD|&=|CE|=a-|AE|
,\quad |CG|=|CF|=a-|BF|
,\\
|DG|&=\Big||CD|-|CG|\Big|
=
\Big|a-r\cot\tfrac\alpha2-(a-r_1\cot\tfrac\alpha2)\Big|
=
\left|r\cot\tfrac\alpha2-r_1\cot\tfrac\alpha2\right|
\\
&=
\Big|r\cdot\frac{a+m-d}{2r}-r_1\cdot\frac{a+c-m-d}{2r_1}\Big|
=\Big|m-\tfrac12 c\Big|
=\tfrac12\Big||AP|- |BP|\Big|
.
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Nice drawing and a little too advanced answer.

Comment: What app did you use for the picture?

Comment: @Dr. Mathva: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
"Asymptote is a powerful descriptive vector graphics language that provides a natural coordinate-based framework for technical drawing. Labels and equations are typeset with LaTeX, for high-quality PostScript output."
Also, you can check out [this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote).

Comment: Thanks @g.kov! The pictures are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the following fact/theorem.

If $ZX$ and $ZY$ are tangents from $Z$ to a circle so that $X,Y$ are touching points, then $ZX = ZY$.

Now it sholud be easy.

**Another hint:** Try to prove $$PG= PK = {PB+PC-BC\over 2}$$

Comment: I know this theorem but I don't know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: Mark a touching points for a start, then write some obviously equations, like  $PG = PA_1$...

Comment: But you mean that I have to mark the other touching points because in my drawing there's only $PG = PA_1$.

Comment: Is that so hard? You don't have to find them, they are there. Just mark them. And put another picture when you do  that.

Comment: Sorry. My English is not good.

Comment: I've updated the drawing.

Comment: I think that I proved that. $PK = PG = x; CG = CJ = z; BK = BJ = y$, thus PK = PG = $\frac {PB + PC - BC}{2} = \frac {x + y + x + z- z - y}{2} = \frac {2x}{2} = x$.

Comment: Yes, and now what is $PI$?

Comment: your picture..........

Comment: I don't know. I suggest $PI=PD=\frac{AP+CP-AC}{2}$.

Comment: Can you prove that

Comment: Yes. It's almost the same as $PK=PG=\frac {PB+PC-BC}{2}$.

Comment: CAn you finsh now?

Comment: Nah. I'm lost now. I just don't understand why we are showing these things. How did you get (come up with) the first equation? From where did you get this idea? To go in this direction... If you weren't here, I would never solve this problem.

Comment: Is not that a problem from a school? Are you not doing that now in school?

Comment: We're doing this at school but I'm trying to solve more problems at home. As you see I get a lot of problems.

Comment: Have you look at how you solve that kind of a problems in a school?

Comment: You didn't understand me. We're doing circles at school but we haven't solved this problem. I'm just exercising at home and I have difficulties with this problem.

Comment: How should I finish?

Comment: Express $DG$ with $PG$ and $PD$

Comment: $DG=PG-PD=\frac {PB+PC-BC}{2} - \frac {AP+CP-AC}{2}=\frac {PB+PC-BC-AP-CP+AC}{2} = \frac {PB-BC-AP+AC}{2}$??

Comment: Come on, you have not read even your own problem! AC = BC!

Comment: You think I haven't read it!????? YES, I have read it 1000 times. If you understand it, it doesn't mean I understand it. If you don't want to help me, just do not do it.

Comment: It isn't necessarily to make me feel like I'm dumb.

Comment: I think that @MariaMazur tries to tell you that, from your last equation $$DG=...=\frac{PB\color{red}{-BC}-AP\color{red}{+AC}}{2}=\frac{PB-AP\color{red}{-BC+AC}}{2}=\frac{PB-AP}{2}$$ which is true since $BC=AC\iff AC-BC=0$. And this is what you have to prove, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Theorem:-       Let A’B’C’ be any triangle with corresponding sides a’, b’, c’ and its semi-perimeter = s’. If its in-circle touches A’B’ at M’, then A’M’ = s’ – a’.

(2) Construct the in-circle of $\triangle ABC$ so that it touches AB at M. To make things a bit easier, I assume the left circle ( in red) is larger than the right circle. Then, CD is on the right side of the median CM.

[image]

(3) From theorem (1), after some algebra, we will get IM = PK.

(4) DG = PG – PD = PI – PK = PI – IM = PM

(5) Result follows from the fact that 2PM = AP – BP